# MultiFile to select multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

does anyone know how to change from single select file (to upload) to multiple upload file? I'm using MultiFile.js. Can this library used for multiple selected file? Since I did multiple at my HTML, but still when I choose more than 1 file, it's only display 1st file name and not all files selected. Is there any possibility that I can loop through my jquery code or whatsoever?

Here is the jquery that i'm using

```
            $(function(){ // wait for document to load
            $('#picture').MultiFile({
           STRING: {
            remove: '<img src="images/bin.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="x"/>'
           }
         });
      });
```

And here my HTML

`<input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" multiple>`

Comment: You can try [Jquery File Upload Plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: @DrixsonOseña that plugin has too much button, 1st need to select, then click upload button, my boss want something simple but with the file name display after choosing it.. :(

Comment: you can remove the start button for each file and just have 1 button to upload them all. Imagine this if you can select many files you should have the option to remove a file that supposedly not to upload and that feature will consume you too much work been there and this plugin save me to the worst case

Answer (score 1):

MultiFile use maxlength property of the input tag to define number of files to upload and the class must be **multi**.

ex :

```
<input type="file" class="multi" maxlength="2"/>
```

Comment: I think maxlength is to limit how many maximum files that can be uploaded, not to handle multiple select files